# I'm having troubles connecting to systems under Cyberark via Remmina under Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, remote-desktop, remmina

I'm having trouble connecting with some remote systems that can be accessed via Cyberark by using Remmina under Linux.

When I try the connection using a web interface, such a web interface downloads a file of this kind: "servername, PSM Address.xxxxxxxx-2a3d-4b9e-9c2f-3c1a84deyyyy.rdp", then the browser use it with Remmina.

After startup, Remmina asks me for username, password and domain.

The username results already compiled and it's like PSM@xxxxxxxx-2a3d-4b9e-9c2f-3c1a84deyyyy (it's the same as the code in the file name). Do I have to change it?

After I input password and domain I receive the reply: "Authentication to RDP server xxx.xxx.xxx failed. Check username, password and domain.".

I tried also to change the username, but nothing changes.

I tried to start Remmina directly and to import the rdp files, but also in this way nothing changes.

The rdp files is something like this:

```
full address:s: xxxxxxxxxxxx
server port:i:yyyy
username:s:PSM@xxxxxxxx-71b5-41cf-9d8d-911a82cfxxxx
alternate shell:s:PSM@xxxxxxxx-71b5-41cf-9d8d-911a82cfxxxx
desktopwidth:i:1024
desktopheight:i:768
screen mode id:i:1
redirectdrives:i:0
drivestoredirect:s:
redirectsmartcards:i:0
EnableCredSspSupport:i:0
redirectcomports:i:0
remoteapplicationmode:i:1
remoteapplicationprogram:s:||PSMInitSession
remoteapplicationname:s:PSM-SSH-zzzzz
disableconnectionsharing:i:1
use multimon:i:0
span monitors:i:0
```

---

Remmina version is: 1.2.0-rcgit-29 (git rcgit-29)

Linux version is:
Linux zarathustra 4.15.0-88-generic #88-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 11 20:11:34 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic

Answer (score 2):

I click "connect via Putty", it downloads the .rdp file then I use `xfreerdp file.rdp`

`sudo apt install freerdp2-x11` to install it on Ubuntu 20

Answer (score 1):

The only way to let this work is by setting the connection manually into Remmina, so using the RDP for Windows function. Until now the connection doesn't work by downloading the RDP file from the PVWA.

You can set the connection in this way:

- Server: PSM address
- Username: your AD username which should also have access to CyberArk (through the PVWA web portal for example)
- Post connection command: `psm /u account /a ip or hostname /c PSM-RDP`

Example: `psm /u administrator /a 10.1.1.2 /c PSM-RDP`

Probably the only problem is that you don't have disk mapping. Another way could also be by using HTML5 gateway.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked after I change:

- **Security protocol negotiation** option to **RDP protocol security**.

This option is in your **Remote Connection Profile** under "**Advanced**" tab.
[See the print on this link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWXx9.png)